# sql query including where doesn't update table without it does?

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
    <?php
session_start();


error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
?>
<?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>'; ?>

    <html>
    <head>
      <title>MR stempagina</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php if( $_SESSION['user_info']['gestemd']>0){
        header("Location: logout.php");
      }
      ?>

      <?php echo $_SESSION['user_info']['name']  ?>, u kunt hier stemmen. 
      <form action="stemmen.php" method="POST">
        <p>Welke ouder wilt u als vertegenwoordiger van de ouders van de HBK afdeling in de medezeggenschapsraad?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="kandidaat" value="piet"> piet<br>
        <input type="radio" name="kandidaat" value="hein"> hein<br>
        <p><input type="submit" name="stem" value="stem"></p>

<?php

$error = '';
  if(isset($_POST['kandidaat'])){
      echo $_POST['kandidaat'];
      $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user;
      //$query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id'];
      //$query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." SET gestemd = gestemd+1";
      //$query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["kandidaat"]." SET aantal = aantal+1";
      //$query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id='{$_SESSION['id']}'";
      $query = "UPDATE {$SETTINGS["USERS"]} SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id={$_SESSION['id']}";
      mysql_query ($query, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$query . ': ' . mysql_error());


    }

?>

          </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

when i use:

```
$query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id='{$_SESSION['id']}'";
```

the table_column gestemd is not incremented.

when i use the same query without the where it works but increment of course all users.

The printR is and echo is for debugging.

thx for your help

Comment: you're updating your entire db without a `WHERE` clause. You know that right?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that i know that it is because i don't use where.

Comment: Check that your value `$_SESSION['id']` is what you expect - it may be empty.

Comment: Have you tried checking the generated query that returns an error? Can you attach it to the question?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: I did a <?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>'; ?> which gave the correct $_SESSION id.

Comment: i used the next query: $query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id'];    the error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /h/b/d/h.nl/public_html/stemmen.php on line 35. This is the query line.

Comment: Thx dn Fer, ik know but i would like to get it work first and then i will make is msqli.

Comment: Nico, the query and the error are in the initial question

Comment: i did some research and altered the query. $query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id='{$_SESSION['id']}'"; now it doesn't give an error but gestemd for user 2 is not incremented while $_SESSION id = 2

Comment: Not really sure why this is being downvoted. It's a fairly reasonable report. More than enough information provided to provide an answer.

Comment: While I'm here anyway, you could improve the formatting here. Try `$query = "UPDATE {$SETTINGS['users']} SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id {$_SESSION['user_id']}";` - means the whole thing doesn't need concatenating. This makes it easier to see you are missing an = before the WHERE component of this query.

Now that we've ruled that out, let's consider other possible issues here. We know that everything in the $_SESSION is likely stored as a string, so it might be worth casting that id to an int before passing it into that query?

Comment: thx Jack, i had to rewrite a little    $query = "UPDATE {$SETTINGS["USERS"]} SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id={$_SESSION['id']}"; but give the same error as in post

Comment: You have started the session before running this query, right? `session_start()`

Comment: I also assume there's more to your code than what we see here, $user isn't set as anything looking at just the above.

Comment: Hi Jack.my post, now the whole code is set.

Comment: Why are you using a database API that's been deprecated for 10 years and hasn't even existed in PHP for 3 years now? https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1255289

Comment: i found an example which works even the code is depreceated. As i already mentioned when it works i will update this code.

Answer (score 0):

i found The answer to the asked question

$query = " UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["USERS"]." SET gestemd = gestemd+1 WHERE id={$_SESSION['user_info']['id']}";

with this solution it works.